# How to validate if the values of four text box is empty string or not and assign these text box as "0" value if it is empty in C# with minimal code

Tags: c#

I have four text box in C#  ,If the value of any text box is :empty string,then it must be assigned as '0'.I have tried the following code which seems to be lenghty .

```
                if (txtReset1.Text == "")
                {
                    txtReset1.Text = "0";
                }

                if (txtReset2.Text == "")
                {
                    txtReset2.Text = "0";
                }

                if (txtReset3.Text == "")
                {
                    txtReset3.Text = "0";
                }

                if (txtReset4.Text == "")
                {
                    txtReset4.Text = "0";
                }
```

Is there any more efficient code than the above one?

Comment: Text box in C# ? Is it in Wpf ?

Comment: lengthy ? You mean it's slow or too verbose ?

Comment: How about not manipulating `Text` property of controls but using data binding instead? When should this code run and how often?

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet I am pretty sure "lengthy" has the meaning of *verbose* here.

Comment: its not in wpf its a simple windows form@RajeevRanjan . lenghty means the line of code that I used seems to be more @ Nicolas Repiquet

Comment: Important note - your code is not checking if the value of the textbox is null, its checking if it is an empty string. These are two different things and you should get in the habit of making sure you use the terms correctly to avoid potential confusion.

Comment: @Chris :Thanks,I have edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than repeat yourself, create a new method to handle it:

```
private void SetEmptyTextBoxToZero(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (textBox != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)
    {
        textBox.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Then you replace your code with:

```
SetEmptyTextBoxToZero(txtReset1);
SetEmptyTextBoxToZero(txtReset2);
SetEmptyTextBoxToZero(txtReset3);
SetEmptyTextBoxToZero(txtReset4);
```

As " Binkan Salaryman" suggests, if you have lots of text boxes that need to be handled this way, then you can store references to them in a list and then iterate over them, rather than listing them out as above:

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { txtReset1, txtReset2, txtReset3, txtReset4 };

...

// Option 1: using .ForEach()
textBoxes.ForEach(tb => SetEmptyTextBoxToZero(tb));

// Option 2: using foreach
foreach (var tb in textBoxes)
{
    SetEmptyTextBoxToZero(tb);
}
```

Comment: Aaand, you may want to put the textboxes in a container for iterating over them... I suggest ``TextBox[]`` or ``List`1`` here.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, good point. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @DavidArno :Whats tb over here??

Comment: @TechBrkTru, I don't follow your question, but I've updated the answer to include using a traditional `foreach` loop if you aren't yet comfortable with lambdas and the `ForEach` method.